# The intrinsic meaning of abelian sheaf cohomology of a category

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, cohomology, topos-theory

Basically my question is:

> Suppose I meet an **alien mathematician which understands everything through category theory** and category theory alone. How would I **convince** said mathematician that **certain cohomology computations are more meaningful than others?**

Let $C \to P := Psh(C)$ be a category embedded inside its presheaf topos.

One has the following diagram for abelian group objects in $C$ and $P$ respectively:

$$\mathsf{AbC \to AbP \to Ab}$$

Where the last morphism comes from the morphism to the terminal topos.

The right arrow is the global sections for presheaves and is a functor between abelian categories. A priori we don't know that $\mathsf{AbC}$ is abelian (we expect it not to be in general) so the composition isn't something we can derive to get cohomology.

In order to define cohomology (so that in particular we get cohomology for abelian group objects) it is reasonable to look for reflective subtoposes of $P$ containing $C$ (image of the yoneda).

Several questions arise in this context:

> 1. What is the name for the **smallest reflective subtopos of $P$ containing $C$**? This should be like the topos of sheaves for the canonical topology - but i'm told that there doesn't always exist a sheafification functor. Is this a pathology which can be rectified by cleverly choosing a "smaller" subcategory of $C$?
> 2. Can we **ensure that the embedding $AbC \to T$** (with $T$ our chosen subtopos) **preserve finite colimits and limits which already exist in
>      $AbC$?** Is this a good thing to ask for if we want to identify good
>      meaningful topologies?

My hope is that given any subcanonical topology on $C$ one can identify the exact sequences in $AbC$ which are preserved by the embedding into the corresponding topos and perhaps treat this subcategory as the one for which the cohomological computations are meaningful.

Examples:

> - I've heard it said that the **zariski topology is enough for coherent sheaves**, does this mean that the **embedding from abelian cones** ("total
>     spaces" of coherent sheaves) **over a scheme to zariski sheaves
>     preserves all exact sequences?**
> - I've heard it said that **etale is enough for smooth group schemes.** Does this mean that the **embedding from smooth group schemes over a
>     scheme to etale sheaves preserves exact sequences?**

I suspect that both points I made above are overly simplistic but I'd very much like to understand this issue.

From an entirely different directions we have for a given topology all the sheafifications of the constant sheaves living in $P$ and these have cohomology groups as well. A priori it seems like all the topologies are on equal footing in this regard.

Comment: You could teach the alien the merits of understanding mathematics from a broader perspective.  :)

Comment: @nfdc23 I'll certainly try. :(

Comment: I feel like I've met some human mathematicians like that.

Comment: Re 1 - if by reflective subtopos you mean full subcategory which is a (Grothendieck) topos and has exact reflector, then by definition this is the topos of sheaves for the canonical topology.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I thought it might happen that the canonical topology doesn't have a sheafification functor because of set theoretic issues. Here i rigged it so that it has a sheafification. I'm not sure the definition through grothendieck topologies is equivalent...

Comment: @WillSawin **The** inspiration for the question.

Comment: @SaalHardali Maybe they were aliens in disguise.

Comment: How so? $C$ is Yoneda embedded in $Psh(C)$ and the canonical topology is by definition the one describing the smallest possible subtopos containing the Yoneda image of $C$. The largest one is the whole $Psh(C)$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Would you agree it is reasonable to assume that the canonical topos being the smallest will have the best chance of preserving limits/colimits of abelian group objects which already exist?

Comment: Limits - maybe. I don't see any reason why colimits would be preserved.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I agree. Although in this trivial example we're actually done from this perspective since there's no information you want to keep.What i'm thinking about is it's reasonable and obvious to ask for your topology to accurately describe principal bundles via $H^1$. This leads naturally to the question of when embedding group objects is exact.